# Is there a way to Bypass or Disable the Exchange UM User Greeting?

Tags: exchange-2010, lync

I have a Lync response group that I'd like to forward to voicemail without playing the greeting. How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Record a greeting that is silent for a few seconds?